# SDL - window doesn't show anything

Tags: c++, linux, sdl-2

I'm doing my first steps in SDL (C++) an took some tutorials from the www.

But there is one problem. I have installed SDL2 on my Linux Mint System, compiled the tutorial code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #include <cstdlib>
#else
    #include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <iostream>

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480,
    SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (win == NULL){
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateWindow Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Renderer *ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1,
    SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (ren == NULL){
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateRenderer Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Surface *bmp = SDL_LoadBMP("cb.bmp");
    if (bmp == NULL){
        std::cout << "SDL_LoadBMP Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Texture *tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, bmp);
    SDL_FreeSurface(bmp);
    if (tex == NULL){
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface Error: "
            << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Delay(4000);

    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

with this compile command:

```
g++ main.cpp -lSDL2 -o prog
```

And I got this:

[image: A window frame without any inside]

A window frame without any inside. Where I have to look for this *error*?

---

---

### Final Code

First: thanks to starrify!

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #include <cstdlib>
#else
    #include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <iostream>

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480,
    SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (window == NULL){
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateWindow Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
/*
    SDL_Renderer *ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1,
    SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (ren == NULL){
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateRenderer Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
*/
    SDL_Surface *surface_bmp = SDL_LoadBMP("cb.bmp");
    if (surface_bmp == NULL){
        std::cout << "SDL_LoadBMP Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
/*
    SDL_Texture *tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, surface_bmp);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface_bmp);
    if (tex == NULL){
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface Error: "
            << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
*/

    SDL_Surface *surface_window = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    /*
     * Copies the bmp surface to the window surface
     */
    SDL_BlitSurface(surface_bmp,
                    NULL,
                    surface_window,
                    NULL);

    /*
     * Now updating the window
     */
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

    /*
     * This function used to update a window with OpenGL rendering.
     * This is used with double-buffered OpenGL contexts, which are the default.
     */
/*    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window); */

    SDL_Delay(5000);

/*    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);*/
/*    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);*/
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Show me this result :)
[image]

I saw that it was truly easy. An in this way I don't need no openGL for drawing. This will be the next step.
It ould be nice, if you help me to improve this example to get it with openGL to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SDL - window doesn't show anything

The reason is that you're not drawing anything. You created a window, a renderer, a surface, and a texture. However you're not *drawing* anything. And the visual result reflects exactly what you've done.

To simply display a BMP image, load the image into a surface and use [`SDL_BlitSurface`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface) to copy it to the screen. Or to work with textures, you shall draw primitives like triangles or quads just like working with OpenGL.

Also another problem: why your window looks filled with other content than a blank screen?
That's because these years the default video mode is set to [double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering), which means there's a front buffer to be shown and a back buffer to render on. When finishing rendering a single frame, you shall call something like [`SDL_Flip`](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlflip.html) (seems it's been obsoleted in SDL2) or [`SDL_UpdateWindowSurface`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UpdateWindowSurface).

**EDITED:** I've edited your code and here's something that works: (removed renderer/texture, added SDL_BlitSurface and SDL_UpdateWindowSurface)

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #include <cstdlib>
#else
    #include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <iostream>

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480,
    SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (win == NULL){
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateWindow Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Surface *bmp = SDL_LoadBMP("cb.bmp");
    if (bmp == NULL){
        std::cout << "SDL_LoadBMP Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_BlitSurface(bmp, 0, SDL_GetWindowSurface(win), 0);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(win);

    SDL_Delay(4000);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using SDL2, you should not be using an SDL_Surface to update the screen.  That's the old way that SDL 1.2 had to use.  The new renderer subsystem is what you want for general use because it is hardware-accelerated (uses the GPU) while SDL_BlitSurface() and SDL_UpdateWindowSurface() are not (all pixel copying is done on the CPU).

So here's what to do.  Do not use SDL_GetWindowSurface().  Use your previous code for creating a renderer and texture.  Replace SDL_BlitSurface() with a call to SDL_RenderCopy().  Replace SDL_UpdateWindowSurface() with a call to SDL_RenderPresent().

Alternatively, you can use SDL_gpu (note: I'm the author), which feels like the older SDL 1.2 blitting API, but has even more features and optimizations than SDL_Renderer.