# SDL2 on Arch Linux: window renders what's on the screen behind it

Tags: c++, linux, sdl, archlinux

I've just started with SDL2, read a couple of articles on it and was able to compile the test program I've written on Arch Linux with success. The only problem that seems to be occurring, is that the window that's being created doesn't render the image. I've tried running the same code on Mac, which does result in the expected. I'm using CLion, which isn't the malefactor, because compiling with g++ through CLI results in the same.

My Arch Linux install:

```
OS: Arch Linux x86_64
Kernel Release: 4.6.2-1-ARCH
```

Here's the code I'm compiling:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
using namespace std;

const int WIDTH = 640;
const int HEIGHT = 480;

bool init();
bool loadMedia();
int close();

SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;
SDL_Surface* image = NULL;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(init())
        if(loadMedia())
            printf("Media loaded");
    SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, surface, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Delay(5000);
    return close();
}

bool init() {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
        printf("Error initializing SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    } else {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if(window == NULL) {
            printf("Error creating window: %s", SDL_GetError());
            return false;
        }
        else
            surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    }
    return true;
}

bool loadMedia() {
    image = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/me/ClionProjects/SDLTest/test.bmp");
    if(image == NULL) {
        printf("Error loading in image: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int close() {
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt file (used by CLion):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(SDLTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -w -lSDL2")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(SDLTest ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

And the Unix command I've used to compile it with g++:

```
g++ main.cpp -w -lSDL2 -o prog
```

What it looks like when running the code on Arch:

[image: Code run on Arch Linux]

I should note that it only copies what's on the screen once, and doesn't update the window content. So when I move the window around, what's rendered in the window stays the same.

On Mac:

[image]

Have found a couple of articles also hinting at this issue, but the solutions to those articles do not work for me. Specifically, I'm talking about these articles.

[SDL - window doesn't show anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953165/sdl-window-doesnt-show-anything)

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188412

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/117792/why-does-sdl-render-the-background-from-the-operating-system-to-the-window

Hope that I've provided enough information, and that there's someone out there that has experienced the same issue and has been able to resolve it. Thanks in advance!

---

Edit after [keltar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109558/sdl2-on-arch-linux-window-renders-whats-on-the-screen-behind-it?noredirect=1#comment63661078_38109558) (still not doing what it's supposed to):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
using namespace std;

const int WIDTH = 640;
const int HEIGHT = 480;

bool init();
bool loadMedia();
//int close();

SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;
SDL_Surface* image = NULL;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(init())
        if(loadMedia())
            printf("Media loaded");
    SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, surface, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Delay(5000);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}

bool init() {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
        printf("Error initializing SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    } else {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if(window == NULL) {
            printf("Error creating window: %s", SDL_GetError());
            return false;
        }
        else
            surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    }
    return true;
}

bool loadMedia() {
    image = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/me/ClionProjects/SDLTest/test.bmp");
    if(image == NULL) {
        printf("Error loading in image: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//int close() {
//    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
//    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
//    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
//    SDL_Quit();
//    return 0;
//}
```

Comment: 1. don't free window surface, and 2. - in most cases (usually with compositing window manager involved) you cannot expect image to appear by simply waiting. Add a loop that flushes event queue, then draws your image, then repeats.

Comment: ...and I've forgot about `close` function, once again. Please don't do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482117/sdl-event-handling-not-working

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll consider them when I'm more fluent with the framework. For now, I'm just following this tutorial, as you might have already deducted: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/index.php
Changing what you suggested didn't change the fact that there's nothing actually being rendered of what I'm asking for it to. The main thing I'm trying to do now, is fix the discrepancy that seems to exist between running this code on Arch Linux and running it on OS X.

Comment: What is your current code? Please add it to the question.

Comment: Added the code to my question. I haven't done anything with event queues yet, so I wasn't able to reproduce that part of the suggestion. Do you think that's where the fault lies? If so, how is it that it does run without prominent fault on OS X?

Comment: Almost sure it is (not the first question with that problem here). I cannot describe reasons for that (and workarounds) in a short comment, will probably post better description later if no other answer will come. Short version is it just happened to work, there is no guarantee about that. To have proper display you have to react to window events apropriately - e.g. redraw when window manager asks you to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run your code on Ubuntu 14.04 without any problem. In order to check if its a 'rendering driver' issue on Linux, could you run my little GPL [game](https://bitbucket.org/josephpaul0/rockdodger-ce/downloads) from the command line and copy-paste the info displayed in the console ?

You should see something like this:

```
Video drivers (2): 'x11' 'dummy', active = 'x11'
Screen: 1920 x 1080, game: 1024 x 576
Rendering drivers (2): 'opengl' 'software', active = 'opengl'
Render flags = 0x000a | ACCELERATED | TARGETTEXTURE
Window flags = 0x001a | OPENGL | BORDERLESS
0 joystick(s) detected
```

I encountered the same kind of problem on CentOS 5 when the 'SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC' flag is ON in the renderer or as long as you don't copy any texture to a renderer.

Another idea, what happens when you do this ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, surface, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I put the image rendering function in a loop, the second iteration around it does actually display the image. Since I plan on making a game, which should render continuously, I don't see a problem in using Arch as my development platform (which is my preferred OS). Still weird that the first call to render results in the content on the screen behind the window to be copied. And it's not just doing that when rendering an image. Trying to color the background red with a rectangle does the same.

Comment: If you plan on making a game, of course you should not use SDL_UpdateWindowSurface() which is 'software' rendered but [2D Accelerated Rendering functions](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryRender) or OpenGL.